# Issues using annotation operator (%<+%), not joining metadata with tip labels from tree

Tags: annotations, left-join, ggtree

My code:

> T6SE_tr (tree file)

Phylogenetic tree with 235 tips and 164 internal nodes.

Tip labels:
36G2_9_Protein_337, 2F9_2_Protein_534, 89F1_10_Protein_44, 28B5_3_Protein_333, 36G2_9_Protein_338, 38D7_6_Protein_1248, ...
Node labels:
, 0.625, 1.000, 1.000, 0.998, 0.999, ...

Unrooted; includes branch lengths.

> tree_metadata (metadata)

## A tibble: 289 × 2

prot_id              Description
                
1 12H11_12_Protein_346 Tde
2 12H11_3_Protein_268  Tde
3 12H11_7_Protein_65   Tde
4 12H11_7_Protein_66   Tde

> T6SE_tr %<+% tree_metadata
> Error in UseMethod("left_join") :
> no applicable method for 'left_join' applied to an object of class "NULL"

I've already checked the structure of both the tree and metadata and they're not NULL. I also made sure that the prot_id values matched the tip labels of the tree. Ive also tried updating the packages. Any thoughts on how to solve the issue? I've done similar trees in the past with no issues but don't know what's wrong with this one.